# Access JDOM elements independent of its namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsd, jdom-2

I have a xml like below:

```
<v2:Root xmlns:v2="www.example.com/xsd/">
<ABC>test data</ABC>
<ABC>test data1</ABC>
<ABC>test data2</ABC>
</v2:Root>
```

When I'm accessing ABC element using JDOM2, i'm getting the element value in debug like

```
[Element:ABC[Namespace:"www.example.com/xsd/"]].
```

That's why i couldn't access the element by just using Xpath expression `"//ABC"`. I'm forced to use expression `"/*[local-name()='ABC']"`.Then it works.

Now, my requirement is to acces the elemnt using expression `"//ABC"` only. Is there any way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken about what your XML actually looks like. I believe you also must have:

```
xmlns="www.example.com/xsd/"
```

in there somewhere otherwise your `ABC` Elements would be in the `NO_NAMESPACE` namespace (and the ABC toString() method would look like: `[Element:ABC]` )

So, your XML snippet does not match the ABC `Element` toString() output.

If you fix your question it will be easier to suggest what your XPath expression should look like.

---

EDIT, assuming I am right that you have the additional redefinition of the default Namespace, then you can use the following JDOM to get the `ABC` elements:

```
XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.instance();
Namespace defns = Namespace.getNamespace("defns", "www.example.com/xsd/");
XPathExpression<Element> xpe = xpf.compile("//defns:ABC", Filters.element(), null, defns);
List<Element> abcs = xpe.evaluate(doc);
```

You should read the following exerpt [from the XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) carefully:

> A QName in the node test is expanded into an expanded-name using the namespace declarations from the expression context. This is the same way expansion is done for element type names in start and end-tags except that the default namespace declared with xmlns is not used: if the QName does not have a prefix, then the namespace URI is null (this is the same way attribute names are expanded). It is an error if the QName has a prefix for which there is no namespace declaration in the expression context.